# Validity in the brevity of this prose?

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

What I intended to write full out was:

> We have moved away from obsoleted
>   technologies and technologies being
>   deprecated.

What I actually wrote feels slightly awkward but I justified leaving it as such because it is concise, sits on my ear in an interesting way and is almost a bit poetic in its simplicity. However what I'm wondering is the validity of the statement:

> We have moved away from obsoleted and
>   technologies being deprecated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> We have moved away from obsoleted and technologies being deprecated.

makes no sense. "Obsoleted" what? You have an adjective and no noun to modify.

You would be better off saying

> We have moved away from technologies that are obsoleted or being deprecated.

Perhaps you could also say something like

> We have moved away from obsoleted and deprecated technologies.

but that sounds very business-speak in a bad way. I don't like the word "obsoleted" anyway. Why not just use "obsolete"?

By the way, obsoleted and deprecated are so similar that you might want to try to combine them.

> We have moved away from obsolescent technologies.

Here "obsolescent" carries both meanings — *osbsoleted* and *being deprecated* — and you're already covered with the past tense because that's the job that "We have moved away ..." performs.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> We have moved away from deprecated or obsolete technologies.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> We have moved away from obsolete and deprecated technologies.

How can you make *obsolete* a transitive verb? I don't get that. And *obsolescent* just seems to be a haughtier means of conveying the fact that the technologies are passé; why not use the simpler adjective?

Comment: In the software world, the term 'deprecated' is similar in meaning to *obsolete*, but where *obsolete* implies that the technology is so old that it is no longer being supported, *deprecated* implies that the technology has been replaced but is still being supported at some level.